# Which encrypted data can reward which level of mark of mods?

Tags: far-cry-3

I haven't played competitive multiplayer, so I wouldn't know about that, but co-operative multiplayer awards encrypted data upon completion of any campaign. Encrypted data can be decoded to win XP or weapon mods. Weapon mods have five marks (i.e., levels of quality). From personal experience, I know that smaller encrypted data (such as CDs and Flash Drives) cannot or practically never reward weapon mods at mark four or five.

I have decoded a lot, so I have many weapon mods, but not all of them are at the highest mark. I'd rather not bother gambling by decoding if the type of encrypted data cannot reward mark five weapon mods. So, specifically, which mods can reward mark five weapon mods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems only Hard Drives and Memory Cards award mark five weapon mods.